# How can I create a decorator with Mapstruct in my Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, decorator, mapstruct

I have a Spring boot application where auto component scan is enabled and mapstruct seems to be set up correctly, since it works on basic mappings created on interfaces, but I can't seem to add a custom decorator to it.

This was my older solution (It is a simple example)

```
@Mapper
public interface CategoryMapper {

    Category mapToCategory(CategoryDTO categoryDTO);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target="imageBase64", expression="java(mapImageToBase64(category.getImage()))"),
    })
    CategoryDTO mapToCategoryDTO(Category category);

    List<Category> mapToCategoryList(List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList);

    List<CategoryDTO> mapToCategoryDTOList(List<Category> categoryList);

    // A default method to handle the IOException
    default String mapImageToBase64(Image image) {
        if (image != null) {
            try {
                return image.getBase64Image();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle the exception in some way (e.g., log an error message and return null)
                System.err.println("Failed to convert image to Base64: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This solution also had a configuration java class, where I manually created a bean for all the mappers I had. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProductMapper getProductMapper() {
        return new ProductMapperImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CategoryMapper getCategoryMapper() {
        return new CategoryMapperImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyMapper getPropertyMapper() {
        return new PropertyMapperImpl();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to opt to not manually create the beans, since auto component scanning is enabled and I would like to extract the extra logic defined in my mapper interfaces into a decorator class, so far I've created this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(value = CategoryMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CategoryMapper {

    Category mapToCategory(CategoryDTO categoryDTO);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "imageBase64", ignore = true)
    })
    CategoryDTO mapToCategoryDTO(Category category);

    List<Category> mapToCategoryList(List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList);

    List<CategoryDTO> mapToCategoryDTOList(List<Category> categoryList);
    
}

public abstract class CategoryMapperDecorator implements CategoryMapper {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private CategoryMapper delegate;

    @Override
    public CategoryDTO mapToCategoryDTO(Category category) {
        System.out.println("Decorator is called.");
        CategoryDTO categoryDTO = delegate.mapToCategoryDTO(category);

        setImageBase64(category, categoryDTO);
        return categoryDTO;
    }

    private void setImageBase64(Category category, CategoryDTO categoryDTO) {
        System.out.println("setImageBase64 is called");
        if (category.getImage() != null) {
            try {
                categoryDTO.setImageBase64(category.getImage().getBase64Image());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle the exception in some way (e.g., log an error message and return null)
                System.err.println("Failed to convert image to Base64: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that the decorator is not generated into the mapper implementation and, therefore the **image64** variable remains null, because I tell the interface to ignore it, since the decorator will make that mapping, but the decorator's code is never called.

The mapper does not work at all without the **"componentModel = "spring"** setting on the **@Mapper**. If I use the default setting or just not give any, I get this error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-03T00:20:38.784+02:00 ERROR 3652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of constructor in hu.maszlag.cms.webshop.category.CategoryService required a bean of type 'webshop.category.adapter.rest.mapper.CategoryMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'webshop.category.adapter.rest.mapper.CategoryMapper' in your configuration.
```

But I don't want to manually define the beans.

Also I've tried putting the **@Component** annotation on the decorator and It does not make a difference.

I'm using **Spring boot 3.0.8** with **gradle**. These are the mapstract dependencies:

```
implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final")
annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final")
```

And these are the generated mapstruct files:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-09-03T00:25:22+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-8.1.1.jar, environment: Java 17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
@Primary
public class CategoryMapperImpl extends CategoryMapperDecorator {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private CategoryMapper delegate;

    @Override
    public Category mapToCategory(CategoryDTO categoryDTO)  {
        return delegate.mapToCategory( categoryDTO );
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> mapToCategoryList(List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList)  {
        return delegate.mapToCategoryList( categoryDTOList );
    }

    @Override
    public List<CategoryDTO> mapToCategoryDTOList(List<Category> categoryList)  {
        return delegate.mapToCategoryDTOList( categoryList );
    }
}

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-09-03T00:25:22+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-8.1.1.jar, environment: Java 17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
@Qualifier("delegate")
public class CategoryMapperImpl_ implements CategoryMapper {

    @Override
    public Category mapToCategory(CategoryDTO categoryDTO) {
        if ( categoryDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Category.CategoryBuilder category = Category.builder();

        category.id( categoryDTO.getId() );
        category.childCategories( mapToCategoryList( categoryDTO.getChildCategories() ) );
        category.name( categoryDTO.getName() );
        category.available( categoryDTO.getAvailable() );
        category.categoryTimestamp( categoryDTO.getCategoryTimestamp() );

        return category.build();
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryDTO mapToCategoryDTO(Category category) {
        if ( category == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CategoryDTO.CategoryDTOBuilder categoryDTO = CategoryDTO.builder();

        categoryDTO.id( category.getId() );
        categoryDTO.name( category.getName() );
        categoryDTO.childCategories( mapToCategoryDTOList( category.getChildCategories() ) );
        categoryDTO.available( category.getAvailable() );
        categoryDTO.categoryTimestamp( category.getCategoryTimestamp() );

        return categoryDTO.build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> mapToCategoryList(List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList) {
        if ( categoryDTOList == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>( categoryDTOList.size() );
        for ( CategoryDTO categoryDTO : categoryDTOList ) {
            list.add( mapToCategory( categoryDTO ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CategoryDTO> mapToCategoryDTOList(List<Category> categoryList) {
        if ( categoryList == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<CategoryDTO> list = new ArrayList<CategoryDTO>( categoryList.size() );
        for ( Category category : categoryList ) {
            list.add( mapToCategoryDTO( category ) );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

I went through the documentation regarding decorations, watched a few youtube videos, github solutions and tried to find anyting on the web, even consolted ChatGPT, but I can't seem to figure out why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your question, you're trying to set the field value for `imageBase64` during the mapping process in `CategoryDTO` to the value of `image.getBase64Image()` in the `Category` object. This sounds like an instance where your mapper needs to be an abstract mapper and you can use the `@AfterMapping`/`@MappingTarget` annotations to achieve what you want.

Your new mapper would look something like the code I have provided below. The `@AfterMapping` annotation marks a method to invoked at the end of the mapping method before the last return statement.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class CategoryMapper {

    public abstract CategoryDTO mapToCategoryDTO(Category category);

    // ... other abstract mapper methods ...

    @AfterMapping
    protected void imageToBase64(Category category, @MappingTarget CategoryDTO dto) {
        dto.setImageBase64(category.getImage().getBase64Image());
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem. Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: My goal is to make the decorators work. While your solution is good for this specific example, my use case requires to use decorators in my project and I was even asked to do so, by a more senior developer. Thanks for your answear, but by any chance do you know why my decorator usage does not work? Any ideas how to properly implement this with decorators?

Comment: did you resolve?